# Scarlett Solo Gen 2 Interface Picks up Audio but Windows doesn't receive anything

Tags: microphones, audio

I'm using an AKG P220 condenser mic, running XLR to the interface and then USB into my computer.

The microphone shows up as "Scarlett Solo USB" which is correct, but when I test the mic, it doesn't output any sound. I've downloaded the requisite drivers for the interface and whenever I speak into it, the gain ring lights up to let me know that it's actually getting signal, so I know the interface is working, it's just not piping anything to the computer from what I can tell.

Things I've tried:

- I've tried turning the gain and monitor both up to no avail.
- I've toggled the Direct Monitor switch on and off and still nothing.
- Phantom power is turned on.
- The interface is set as the default recording device in Windows.
- Running a test in Audacity gives me the error: *"Error while opening sound device. Please check the recording device settings and the project sample rate."* (both are set to 44100)

Again, the interface is clearly picking up the microphone, it's just that it's as if it's not being passed along to Windows properly, which is extremely odd.

Any solutions?

Comment: What application is receiving (or not receiving) the audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what I just learned with doing some more testing is that **"Scarlett Solo USB"** is ***NOT*** what you want to see if the device is hooked up.

For the device to be properly configured for Windows, you should see it as **"Focusrite USB"**.

If your interface is getting signal, but Windows is not interpreting that input, then that is a Windows driver issue. More than likely Windows recognized the device when you inserted it into the USB port, which caused whatever drivers on the interface itself to be loaded. These are not the correct drivers and will continue to override the proper drivers until they're uninstalled.

If you've already tried installing the drivers, here's what I did to fix the problem.

- Keep the interface plugged into the computer.
- Uninstall the current drivers by going into the ***Device Manager > Audio Inputs and Outputs*** and then uninstalling the drivers to the interface.
- With the device plugged in, reinstall the drivers provided by the manufacturer and restart your computer.
- At this point, the audio interface should be working properly.